# Are there Generalizations of this theorem I found on a chit of paper?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Some time ago , I was reading a book which was not of a mathematical taste from a library . But from that book a chit of paper came out which was handwritten and had the title : Aubry's theorem
And it read

> ```
>                               Aubry's theorem
> ```
>
> Any group of 30 consecutive odd numbers does not contain more than 15 prime numbers or numbers all of whose prime factors exceed 7.

It was a very curious result for me and I turned the paper back and forth but what I could find was just a date :$25 -3-97$ and nothing else.

My question here is are there generalizations of this result , What changes can we make in those pairs of numbers $(30,15,7)$ ?

Comment: A chit of paper?

Comment: @Oliver  Sure .... it wasn't a A4 sized paper

Comment: @Oliver Wiktionary calls it a "dated" term for a scrap of paper. Maybe in India it still has currency.

Comment: @JackM oh ..sorry I did not know its defination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basis of the [number wheel in prime sieve algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization), in this case the 7-wheel.

The step before is the 3-wheel, which gives that any prime number must have the form $6k\pm1$. Using additionally the factor 5 gives the 5-wheel with a period of 30, and among the remaining remainders

```
 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29
```

the ones divisible by 5 will never belong to prime numbers, reducing the list to

```
 1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29
```

resulting in 8 prime number candidates among every segment of 15 odd numbers.

One can further refine this argument by using the 7-wheel, which has a period of 210 and excludes remainders divisible by 7

```
  1,   _   11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29, 
 31,  37,  41,  43,  47,   _   53,  59, 
 61,  67,  71,  73,   _   79,  83,  89, 
  _   97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 119,
121, 127, 131,  _   137, 139, 143, 149,
151, 157,  _   163, 167, 169, 173, 179,
181, 187, 191, 193, 197, 199,  _ , 209
```

and indeed in every segment of 60 numbers or 30 odd numbers there is at least one remainder eliminated as divisible by 7.